# Problems with saving to external USB Flash Storage

Tags: usb, fat32, flash-memory, macos

I have an external USB Flash storage which is generally realiable.

When editing text files on the drive I *often* get the message:

```
The document “…” could not be saved. The file doesn’t exist.
```

However, sometimes it does save successfully.

I have formatted the flash drive first as `ExFAT` and later as `FAT32` (it is 64Gb); `FAT32` appears to be a little more reliable, but it hasn’t solved the problem. I have also tried attaching the drive first to a powered USB hub, and later directly to the back. Again, it doesn’t help.

What might be causing this problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

From your problem description your filesysyem might be damaged.
Check this with `Disk Utility > verify`.

**If** `Disk Utility` does report any error

**then** fix them.

Next run `verify` many times (10 is what I use) on your USB key.

**If** errors appear,

**then** your USB is aging and start to behave
badly when heating,
in this case: change it;

**else** problem fixed.